# sorry ubuntu has encountered an internal error /usr/bin/compiz with 16.04 on start

Tags: nvidia, graphics, compiz, 16.04

I have just installed 16.04 as dual boot with Windows 10. MSI z170a M3 MB Nvidia gtx980Ti. I get this error:

```
Sorry Ubuntu has experienced an internal error. /usr/bin/compiz Have checked MD5 and reinstalled.
```

Get the same error using live version. Login gives me background but no desktop. Terminal is also blank.

Any advice appreciated. Never used Ubuntu before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)